# MySQL UPDATE - updating multiple rows?

Tags: mysql, sql-update

```
mysql_query("UPDATE `users` SET `balance` = 0 WHERE `username` = '$uid' AND '$ip'");
```

How would I make it update the database where the username is equal to the UID or if the username is equal to the $ip?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do it:

```
UPDATE `users`
  SET `balance` = 0
WHERE `username` IN ('$uid','$ip')
```

equivalent to

```
UPDATE `users`
  SET `balance` = 0
WHERE `username` = '$uid'
   OR `username` = '$ip'
```

Answer (score 0):

Almost like you say it in English ;)

```
mysql_query("UPDATE `users` SET `balance` = 0 WHERE `username` = '$uid' or `username` =  '$ip'");
```